# Mobile master page mark-up duplicates on link click but only on a desktop browser

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

[EDIT: these were not made with an asp Mobile.Master template, rather just a normal master with the mobile specific mark-up in Visual Studio 2010]

[EDIT 2: the site just went up as it was fine in the emulators just not on the web browser, but now it doesn't work on mobiles either. The same thing happens]

I have made a mobile version of our website, just a simple "/m-en-US" and "/m-de-AT" -- which is how my boss wants it. The page shows fine on a mobile browser, I can navigate everywhere without a problem. But when I run it in a desktop browser and click on any navigation link the mark up duplicates and a `div` disappears. Can you help me figure out what's wrong?

The Home and Find Us links are both `asp:menuitems` but the others are just links no matter what is clicked this happens. There is no significant code behind. If I need to show more code or details please just say.

Thank you.

[image: Before click][image: After click, green bar is gone but the links still function but the page and form mark-up is doubled]

This is the only code that could be relevant really:

```
<div class="header">
        <asp:Menu ID="NavMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/m-en-US/start.aspx" Text="Home" />
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/m-en-US/Directions.aspx" Text="Find Us" />
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/m-de-AT/Start.aspx">
            <!--Flag images via http://www.icondrawer.com-->
            <img src="Images/at.png" id="flagImage" alt="Deutsch" />
    </asp:HyperLink>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite messing around with the fixed heights before I finally found the solution by setting the `div` height to precisely `41.59675px` and setting the width in the NavMenu directly as `159px` I have no idea how or why this works but it does.